# JSON Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(Swift 5.3)

Tags: json, swift

I'm new in Swift and im trying to decode a JSON but it doesn't work.

This is the JSON code:

```
[
  {
    "LocalObservationDateTime": "2021-02-09T21:11:00+01:00",
    "EpochTime": 1612894260,
    "WeatherText": "Sunny",
    "WeatherIcon": 36,
    "HasPrecipitation": false,
    "IsDayTime": false,
    "Temperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 15.2,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 59,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "MobileLink": "http://m.accuweather.com/",
    "Link": "http://www.accuweather.com/"
  }
]
```

and this is the struct I have created:

```
struct CurrentConditions : Decodable{
    let localObservationDateTime: String?
    let epochTime: Int
    let weatherText: String
    let weatherIcon: Int
    let hasPrecipitation: Bool
    let isDayTime: Bool
    let temperature: Temperature
}

struct Temperature : Decodable{
    let metric: Metric
    let imperial: Imperial
}

struct Imperial : Decodable{
    let value: Int
    let unit: String
    let unitType: Int
}

struct Metric : Decodable{
    let value: Double
    let unit: String
    let unitType: Int
}
```

```
let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(CurrentConditions.self, from: jsonData)
```

I used this code to decode but all variables came as nil.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZK3l.png)

Decoder can solve the struct but it comes as nil. When I put "CurrentConditions" inside array(like so: [CurrentConditions]) decoder can't solve the struct and object(response) comes as nil.

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>,
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file
JSON_Test/ViewController.swift, line 52
2021-02-10 13:13:22.429097+0300 JSON Test[7884:534414] Fatal error: 'try!' expression
unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String,
Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file
JSON_Test/ViewController.swift, line 52
```

Comment: Please look at the JSON. It starts with a `[` which represents an array. That's exactly what the error message says. Decode `[CurrentConditions].self`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your content is an array not a dictionary, you need `[CurrentConditions].self`

```
do {
     let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([CurrentConditions].self, from: jsonData)
 }
catch {
  print(error) 
}
```

Always avoid `try!` and use `do catch` block

Comment: Thanks for answer! Now I get this output: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "epochTime", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"epochTime\", intValue: nil) (\"epochTime\").", underlyingError: nil))

It comes nil. Maybe I do something wrong on struct?

Comment: @OronaCastal Please (learn to) **read** the stuff. The key (as well as the other keys) is uppercase, the struct member is lowercase. Add `Codingkeys`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that uppercase affects, the problem is solved now thank you all.

Comment: A general tip is to learn how to extract the core error (Expected to decode
Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead) and then search for it here before posting